# Where is NuGet in VS2017 Community?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

Just installed VS2017 Community edition -- I read some doc saying that NuGet is included -- but I don't see it and don't see how to add it.  Should it appear basically as it did in VS2015?

Comment: It's integrated in the same way 2015 has it.

Comment: Simply go to tools.

Comment: I figured it out -- when you run the VS2017 installer, of course there are many options presented.  I hadn't selected an option which caused Nuget to be installed.  finally, I had to go back and download the installer again, and re-install VS2017, this time looking carefully at the dozens of check boxes, and making sure to ask for it.  I don't think the documentation is very good, which just says "its included in VS2017" - that makes it sound like you should see it in every VS2107 install - not the case - it depends.

Comment: btw, when installing vs 2017, the "Visual Studio Installer" is installed on your machine and you can always click "modify" so you don't need to re-install your whole VS, but the installer can add/remove components at any time

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI  If I go to Tools, and select Package manager Console, then type in (e.g.) "nuget spec" (as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package), I get "The term 'nuget' is not recognized".

Comment: Go to Tool>Nuget Package Manger.

Answer (score 8):

You have to find it in the installer, second tab - "Packages", under the subheading "Code Tools"

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWtAX.png]

You can launch the installer from the Tools menu in VS, it should be the first option.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. When I installed VS 2017, I only had Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Package. I can't remember how I figured it out, but I did. What you have to do is:

1. Open VS 2017.
2. Select **Tools** > **NuGet Package Manager** > **Package Manager Settings**.
3. In **Options**, select **NuGet Package Manager** > **Package Sources**.
4. Select **+** next to **Available package sources**.
5. Enter these values:

   - Name: *nuget.org*
   - Source: *https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json*
6. Select **OK**.

Now, when you run `Install Package` commands, you'll get what you need.

**NOTE**: *In the **Package Manager Console**, as your **Package source**, make sure you select **All** or **nuget.org***.

Answer (score 4):

It was included as an option, NOT installed by default.
To install NuGet:
 1. `Tools` > `Get Tools and Features...`
 2. `Single Component` > `Code Tools`
 3. `√` NuGet package manager
 4. update.
To find NuGet:
 - `Project` >  `Manage NuGet packages...`
 - `Tools` > `NuGet Package Manager`

Project or Tools

Comment: It's called "Individual Components" on my machine, not "Single Component". (VS 2017 Community Edition, version 15.8.6).

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017, 
Click on Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbled across this question while trying to find out where `nuget` was installed to use it as a CLI, if you didn't install it individually you need to use it through `MsBuild.exe`'s use of `/t:restore` to for example restore nuget packages. You'll have to install the individual component if you want the full tool and not just calls to a DLL via MSBuild.